# i have a set of account numbers to which i have to map 12 months data in respective months column

Tags: sql, sql-server

i  have a set of account numbers .i need to map values for 12 months against the account numbers in their respective month.

While using a update query it throws more than 1 value is being thrown .
please suggest.

```
upate balances
set inrambfeb14=feb14.inramb 
from feb14 
where balance.accountno=feb14.accountno
```

Comment: please provide valid of whole query.

Answer (score 0):

```
 with cte as ( select accountNo,max(inramb) inramb  from feb14 group by accountNo )
update balances set inrambfeb14 = cte.inramb   
from cte join balances bal on bal.accountno = cte.accountno
```

This will give you max value to update...

for more suitable answers you should give some input data & your expectation clearly

Answer (score 0):

There must be multiple records for one account, and hence the error.
you must have some logic to get distinct **inramb** data per account to run this successfully.

Like the one vignesh is suggesting i.e. max of data.